# Android, how to know specific target of DragListener

Tags: android, drag

Hi everyone i'm trying to implement a drag and drop custom system and i'm struggling at the very last part. On my method:

```
 @Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED: break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED: break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED: break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            View dragged = (View) event.getLocalState();
            Log.e("DROPPED", "?");
            Log.e("DRAGGED VIEW = " + dragged.toString(), "?");
            Log.e("TARGET = " + getResources().getResourceName(v.getId()), "?");
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED: break;
        default: break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This works pretty fine, my problem is that as a target i get the parent root view instead of the specific layout where i want to place the draggable.

How can i achieve that my target is recognized where the drop ended? Do i have to compare X and Y coords or there is another more practical method?

I want to point out that mi parent root view has like 2 layouts inside, but wherever i end the drop event always get's the parent ID as a result, not the child ones.

Answer (score 0):

Okey in case someone is as stu... as i am. The problem was that i defined the setOnDragListener in the parent layout instead of the child where i wanted the draggable items to be placed.